# Opacity Issue when drawing texture

Tags: swift, opengl, opengl-es

So i have been trying to draw a texture for awhile now.  And I ran into a new snag.  I was wondering if I could force the transparency of each pixel so I changed the generic fragment shader and forced the alpha to be 0.5.  Unfortunately this has created a very weird effect.  Here is the edited shader code

```
precision highp float;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

uniform sampler2D s_texture;

void main()
{
    vec4 color = texture2D(s_texture, v_texcoord);
    float r = color.z;
    float g = color.y;
    float b = color.x;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(r, g, b, 0.5);
}
```

Basically what it is rendering is the top triangle bright, and the low triangle darker (suggesting that the occupancy is working)

```
func drawTriangle(texture: GLuint)
    {
        loadBuffers()
        //glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
        //glClearColor(0, 0.0, 0, 1.0)
        //glClear(GLbitfield(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) | GLbitfield(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT))


        glEnable(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D))
        glActiveTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE0))

        glUseProgram(texShader)
        let loc1 = glGetUniformLocation(texShader, "s_texture")
        glUniform1i(loc1, 0)


        let loc3 = glGetUniformLocation(texShader, "matrix")
        if (loc3 != -1)
        {
            glUniformMatrix4fv(loc3, 1, GLboolean(GL_FALSE), &matrix)
        }

        glBindTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), texture)
        glDrawArrays(GLenum(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP), 0, 6)
        glDisable(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D))

        destroyBuffers()
    }
func destroyBuffers()
    {
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &vb)
        //glDeleteVertexArraysOES(1, &vb)
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &tc)
    }
    func loadBuffers()
    {
        buildArrays()
        //****Load up the vertex data******
        //Make a buffer object for it
        glGenBuffers(1, &vb)
        glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), vb)
        glBufferData(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), sizeof(GLfloat) * n_gVertexData.count, n_gVertexData, GLenum(GL_STATIC_DRAW))


        //Bind the buffer to the shader
        GLKVertexAttribPosition = GLuint(glGetAttribLocation(texShader, "positionCoords"))
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition)
        glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));



        //******Load up all the texture coords*******
        //Make a buffer for texture coords
        glGenBuffers(1, &tc)
        glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), tc)
        glBufferData(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), sizeof(GLfloat) * n_cubeTexture.count, n_cubeTexture, GLenum(GL_STATIC_DRAW))

        //Bind the buffer to the shader location
        aTexCoordLoc = GLuint(glGetAttribLocation(texShader, "textureCoords"))
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(aTexCoordLoc);
        glVertexAttribPointer(aTexCoordLoc, 2, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0))


        //Just the sampler for the texture position
        uSamplerLoc = glGetUniformLocation(texShader, "s_texture")

    }
func buildArrays()
    {
        //print("Building arrays")
        n_gVertexData = []

        var state:Int = 1
        for var i = 0; i < n_cubeTexture.count; i++
        {
            if (state == 1)
            {
                state = 2
                n_gVertexData.append(n_cubeTexture[i] * GLfloat(width * 1))
            }
            else if (state == 2)
            {
                state = 1
                n_gVertexData.append(n_cubeTexture[i] * GLfloat(height * 1))
                n_gVertexData.append(0)
            }
        }

    }
    var n_gVertexData:[GLfloat] = [0.0, 0, 0,    0, 200, 0,    0, 200, 0.0,
        200, 0.0, 0,     200, 200, 0.0,       0.0, 200, 0.0]

    //TR, BR, TL
    var n_cubeTexture:[GLfloat] = [0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0]
```

Does anyone know what might cause this to happen? I am using the same shader each time.
[image: Cool Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vertices are wrong.

```
var n_gVertexData:[GLfloat] = [0.0, 0, 0,    0, 200, 0,    0, 200, 0.0,
        200, 0.0, 0,     200, 200, 0.0,       0.0, 200, 0.0]
```

The second and the third vertex are identical.

Also, you have 6 vertices and you draw a GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, which only needs 4 vertices to draw a rectangle.

[image]

So that means that you draw 4 triangles. My guess is, is that the brighter half of your rectangle is actually drawn twice - which explains why it looks brighter.

Either change your vertices to match a triangle strip (and texture coordinates accordingly) or fix your current vertices and change it to GL_TRIANGLES.

Comment: Sorry my code is a bit deceptive.  I actually build n_gVertexData based on n_cubeTexture.  That way the square can be set by the size of the screen.  The vertexes are built in the "buildarrays" . So I doubt that is why but I can test later.  Could having the triangle coordinates go in the wrong order cause this?

Comment: Even if your vertices are generated some other way - you still draw 6 vertices as a triangle strip - meaning you draw 4 triangles (See picture). The  brighter half you see are probably two overlapping triangles.